# GMSMarker add animation like iOS Annotation pin

Tags: ios, google-maps, gmsmapview

I am using Google maps in my iOS app and i want to add animation to GMSMarker like iOS default Annotation pin which comes from top and get placed nicely over the map.

Thanks!

Comment: Please read my question.I have already gone through links that you have provided.This is not what I wanted.

Comment: @Anbu Can you please give me link of post which is duplicate of my question?Atleast read the question carefully